# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' Rest Service, jsonp, Jquery, Safari

Tags: jquery, rest, safari, jsonp

I am getting the following in Safari

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

However web inspector does show `"{"SessionIDResult":"2203962588888734388888896891"}"` if I click on the error, so the data is being returned from the server.

Service Code:

```
namespace RestService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "sid/{sUserID}/{sPassword}/{sDatabase}")]
            string SessionID(string sUserID, string sPassword, string sDatabase);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
            string JSONData(string id);
    }
}
```

Jquery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:35798/RestServiceImpl.svc/sid/sk/sk/system1',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/json",
    jsonp: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'Callback',
    success: function(){alert("success");}
});
});
```

I have been trying to solve this all week so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could it be that you are trying to use ordinary JSON as JSONP? JSONP requires that the data is wrapped in a function call. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for an example. What is your payload/response body?

Comment: Your jQuery shows a double `});` - I'm assuming that's a typo - other than that,.. what Augustus said sounds possible! =) Is it just Safari, or does it work/fail in other browsers?

Comment: Extra }); is from the on document ready which I chopped off...

Comment: Thanks I think I understand what your saying Augustus. I will have another go and report back.